# How do I keep from cycling through an entire array when trying to access an index in a parallel array

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and coding in general.
Basically, when I ask the user if they would like extra toppings, I'm setting the answer to a Boolean. The problem is that when they select true the array cycles through every index. Is there a problem with my for loop?

I tried using different parameters in the for loop.

```
string[] size = { "small", "medium", "large", "x-large" };
double[] price = {6.99, 8.99, 12.50, 15.00};
double[] extra = { 1.00, 2.00, 3.25, 4.50 }; //extra toppings

            Console.Write("Pizza Sizes: Small, Medium, Large, X-Large ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Enter a the pizza size you would like to order:");

            string pizzaSize = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You selected size  {0}:", pizzaSize);

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like extra toppings? true or false?");
            bool addons = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("You selected {0}", addons);

            for (int i = 0; i < size.Length; i++)

            {
                if (size[i] == pizzaSize)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You ordered a {0} pizza for ${1}", pizzaSize, price[i]);
                }

                if (addons == true)

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You ordered a {0} pizza with extra toppings. The total price is {1}", pizzaSize, price[i] + extra[i]);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
```

If the customer only wants a pizza of a certain size, the array should return the price of the pizza, however if the customer would like to add toppings, the parallel array should return the total price of the pizza plus the extra toppings.

Comment: First I'd recommend creating a class to hold the related data of size, price, and extra.  That way all the related data can be put into a collection together instead of separate collections.

Comment: Consider making your sizes an enum (`enum PizzaSize {Small, ... };`.  Then declare both your size and extra toppings collections as dictionaries using the PizzaSize type as a key (`Dictionary<PizzaSize, decimal>`).  You can get the sizes as string from the type using `System.Enum.GetNames()`.  Once you have a size you can lookup both the price and the topping price with no loop at all.  By the way, you are going to want to put some error checking in your code - user's never type things in correctly.

Comment: delicious question :-).  Your code doesn't compile, even in LinqPad, because you are missing a closing brace.  My guess is that you want it right before the final  Console.ReadLine() statement, since the ReadLine() doesn't belong inside the for loop.

Comment: Ahh my mistake I missed the closing curly brace when I copied things over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you need to loop only once and only trough `size` array to find an index corresponding to the entered pizza size.

By the way, in real life you should also expect invalid input and handle such situation.
Also `decimal` should be better for handling prices, to avoid `0.999999999` instead of `1` after math operations.

Please see the below example.
Instead of `while` you could use `for` and `break` from it if match found, it is a question of personal preference...

```
const int arraySize = 4;
string[] pizzaSizes = { "Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large" };
decimal[] prices = { 6.99M, 8.99M, 12.50M, 15.00M };
decimal[] extras = { 1.00M, 2.00M, 3.25M, 4.50M }; //extra toppings

Console.WriteLine("Pizza Sizes: Small, Medium, Large, X-Large ");
Console.Write("Enter a the pizza size you would like to order:");

string pizzaSize = Console.ReadLine();
int i = 0;
// Important to have condition (i < arraySize) the first in evalution 
while ((i < arraySize) && (pizzaSizes[i] != pizzaSize))
{
    ++i;
}

if (i >= arraySize)
{
    // Invalid input
    Console.WriteLine($"Invalid pizza size input: {pizzaSize}. Exiting");
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("You selected a {0} pizza for ${1}", pizzaSizes[i], prices[i]);

Console.WriteLine("Would you like extra toppings? true or false?");
bool addons = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("You selected {0}", addons);

if (addons)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"You ordered a {pizzaSizes[i]} pizza with extra toppings. The total price is {prices[i] + extras[i]}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"You ordered a {pizzaSizes[i]} pizza without extra toppings. The total price is {prices[i]}");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is perfect. I am using for loops at the moment because I really want to get used to them. I am making separate console files from everyone's suggestions here so I can study the different solutions. This is great thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented faulty logic in your code.

Your for-loop will loop through like usual, if user want topping (as addons == true), it will run the code this code:

Console.WriteLine("You ordered a {0} pizza with extra toppings. The total price is {1}", pizzaSize, price[i] + extra[i]);

Since it is a loop, it will run every time when addons == true. First at i = 0, then i = 1 etc.

If you found this helpful, mark solved. Good luck. :)

---

EDIT:

Considering putting the if inside the if.

Comment: So simple but it worked. I'm always careful about nesting. I'm not that comfortable with it yet, but this helps thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing information in the loop.  All you really want the loop to do is identify the correct size index so you can use that to reference the other arrays though, right?

```
int selSize = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < size.Length; i++)
{
    if (size[i] == pizzaSize)
    {
        selSize = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (addons == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You ordered a {0} pizza with extra toppings. The total price is {1}", pizzaSize, price[selSize] + extra[selSize]);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You ordered a {0} pizza for ${1}", pizzaSize, price[selSize]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This way, the loop does only what it needs to do, and you bring your logic you don't need looped outside of it's block.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was actually thinking about creating a new variable (totalCost) but wasn't sure how to use it. I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it.  First an enum for the sizes:

```
public enum PizzaSize
{
    Small,
    Medium,
    Large,
    XLarge,
}
```

Then, the pricing information:

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<PizzaSize, decimal> PizzaPrices = new Dictionary<PizzaSize, decimal>
    {
        {PizzaSize.Small, 6.99m},
        {PizzaSize.Medium, 8.99m },
        {PizzaSize.Large, 12.50m },
        {PizzaSize.XLarge, 15.00m }
    };
    private static readonly Dictionary<PizzaSize, decimal> ToppingsPrices = new Dictionary<PizzaSize, decimal>
    {
        {PizzaSize.Small, 1.00m},
        {PizzaSize.Medium, 2.00m },
        {PizzaSize.Large, 3.25m },
        {PizzaSize.XLarge, 4.50m }
    };
```

Then a simple parser for the True/False answer (note that I'm liberal on what I take):

```
 private static bool TryParseTrueFalse(string answer, out bool response)
 {
     if (new[] { "Y", "Yes", "T", "True" }.Contains(answer, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
     {
         response = true;
         return true;
     }

     if (new[] { "N", "No", "F", "False" }.Contains(answer, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
     {
         response = false;
         return true;
     }

     response = false;
     return false;
 }
```

And finally, a function to put it all together.  Note that there is no loop at all in this (well other than looping if the user answers the questions incorrectly):

```
public static void GetPizza()
{
    var pizzaSizesString = string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(PizzaSize)));
    Console.WriteLine($"Pizza sizes: {pizzaSizesString}");
    Console.Write("Enter the size of the pizza you want: ");
    PizzaSize pizzaSize = PizzaSize.Small;
    bool answerOk = false;
    while (!answerOk)
    {
        var size = Console.ReadLine();
        answerOk = Enum.TryParse(size, out pizzaSize);
        if (!answerOk)
        {
            Console.Write(@"Please enter one of: {pizzaSizesString}");
        }
    }
    Console.Write("Would you like extra toppings on that (true/false): ");
    bool toppings = false;
    answerOk = false;
    while (!answerOk)
    {
        var toppingsString= Console.ReadLine();
        answerOk = TryParseTrueFalse(toppingsString, out toppings);
        if (!answerOk)
        {
            Console.Write(@"Please enter true or false: ");
        }
    }

    var toppingNote = toppings ? " with extra toppings" : string.Empty;
    var price = PizzaPrices[pizzaSize];
    if (toppings)
    {
        price += ToppingsPrices[pizzaSize];
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"You ordered a {pizzaSize} pizza{toppingNote} for a total of {price}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: And the down-vote is for?  There's no need for a loop at all - this should be an O(1) operation, not O(N). Yes, it's more advanced than the original code, but, it compiles and runs.  The OP can take it, step through it, google any calls or concepts that he/she doesn't understand.  That's how you learn

Comment: Downvote was accidental sorry(I'm not sure if it was me that downvoted). Your Solution is a bit advanced for me, but using it will help me learn. I copied it to a new console project to study. Thanks again.

Comment: @haberjin: the main thing is this statement (and the similar statement for the toppings): `var price = PizzaPrices[pizzaSize];`.  It looks the price of the pizza up in the dictionary using the size that the user entered.  That way you don't need to loop through the sizes, you let the dictionary's lookup table do the work.

Comment: That took me a while but I actually think I get it. I never learned about creating directories so this was really helpful.